# createPattern(backgroundImg, "repeat"); returns null

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
var backgroundImg = new Image(50, 50);
backgroundImg.src = "img/grass.png";
var backgroundPattern = screen.createPattern(backgroundImg, "repeat");
```

backgroundPattern is null. Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to give the image time to load. For this, use the `onload` handler on the Image instance. Note that this is asynchronous so you need to have that in mind for the rest of the code:

```
var backgroundPattern;
var backgroundImg = new Image(50, 50);

backgroundImg.onload = function() {
    // provided screen holds the 2D context of the canvas:
    backgroundPattern = screen.createPattern(this, "repeat");    

    // execute next part of your code from here... 
    // next();
};

backgroundImg.src = "img/grass.png";
```